# Did I get this BJT configurations correct?

Tags: transistors, bjt

I'm trying to learn what kind of BJT transistors are this:
Did I get them right?

[image: BJTS]

Comment: (1) has power and ground and an input, but no output shown. (2) may, assuming signal flows left to right, have power, ground, input and output all shown. (3) has power, input, and output shown, but no ground for the BJT circuit.

Comment: @ Ε. Ντελιλαι, Where should you apply the input voltage in the common-base configuration?

Comment: @Ε. Ντελιλαι, In this classification, "common" has the meaning of "AC grounded". So, the transistor terminal that does not change when the input voltage varies, gives the circuit name. "Common base" means the base voltage is fixed; then the emitter voltage must vary. As a result, the transistor input (base-emitter) voltage will vary. So correct the second picture according to these considerations...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's try to find some sense in this formal classification...

**Transistor vs circuit input.** The input of the bipolar transistor is its base-emitter junction; so there we have to apply the input voltage. In the general case, the base-emitter junction is floating... but we prefer to deal with single-ended (grounded) voltages. Then we present the floating base-emitter voltage as a difference between two single-ended input voltages. Note they are "circuit-input voltages" while the base-emitter voltage is "transistor-input voltage". You can see the same difference in op-amp amplifying circuits. For example, in an op-amp inverting amplifier, VIN is the circuit-input voltage... while V(+) - V(-) is the op-amp input voltage.

So, we can drive the transistor in a few ways giving the names in this classification:

**Common-emitter stage.** In this configuration, we fix the emitter voltage (by inserting another voltage source, Zener diode, capacitor... or simply grounding the emitter). Then we vary the base voltage (i.e., we drive the transistor *from the side of the base*). When the input base voltage increases, the collector current increases and the collector voltage decreases; so this is an *inverting amplifier*.

**Common-base stage.** Now we fix the base voltage and vary the emitter voltage (we drive the transistor *from the side of the emitter*). When the input emitter voltage increases, the base-emitter voltage decreases, the collector current decreases and the collector voltage increases; so this is a *non-inverting amplifier*.

**Common-collector stage.** Here the collector voltage is fixed at +VCC  (as though the collector is AC grounded); hence the name "common-collector". But this is a formal statement that has nothing to do with the transistor-input voltage; it only serves to somehow put another circuit in this classification. As above, the input voltage has to be applied between the base and emitter. So, like in the common-emitter stage, we apply the circuit-input voltage to the base (drive the transistor *from the side of the base*) but here the transistor produces the emitter voltage. It does it by passing its collector current through an emitter resistor - the so-called *emitter degeneration*). So, when the input base voltage increases, the collector current increases, the emitter voltage increases thus decreasing the base voltage and collector current. The result is the emitter voltage follows the base voltage; the circuit acts as a *voltage follower*.

**Common-emitter stage with emitter degeneration.** This is a combination of common-emitter and common-collector stages since resistors are inserted in both collector and emitter. This circuit is difficult to fit into the classification because, in practice, it has no common (fixed) terminal. If we shunt the emitter resistor by a capacitor, it will become an "AC common-emitter stage".

**Differential stage.** Finally, we can control the transistor-input voltage by changing simultaneously both circuit-input voltages. First we can do it in a *differential* manner changing them in opposite directions. The collector current and voltage will change more vigorously than in the case of the common-emitter and common-base stage.

Then, we can do it in a *common-mode* manner changing them in the same direction. Their difference across the base-emitter junction will not change; the collector current and voltage will not change as well.

---

I think that after these explanations, you should be able to correct your circuits so that they fit into the classification.

Comment: Well put I think the OP should put this as the answer, even though I think he just wants us to mark his homework for him.

Comment: @crowie, I think it is not very suitable for homework because it is too philosophical:) and does not give an exact answer for the specific OP circuits. Rather, I hope his teacher can use it to introduce this formal classification in a somewhat intriguing way...

Comment: @Circuitfantasist thank you sir, very helpful!!

Answer (score 1):

All of the **transistors** are NPN BJTs. It is the **complete amplifier circuit** that might be common-emitter or common-collector.

For your "common emitter" circuit you need to show us where the output signal is taken. If from the transistor's collector then indeed this is a common-emitter amplifier.

The "common base" circuit is another common-emitter amplifier.

Comment: Thank you. For the "common emitter" the output is from the collector. So that makes it common collector?